# FileHandle prevents File.Move

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, filestream, filehandle

I am trying to figure out why the following code prevents overwriting of the file used in the filestream.

> This only happens when using **Cut and Paste**, **Copy and Paste**
> works weirdly enough

```
var fs = new FileStream(
    File.OpenHandle(
        path,
        mode: FileMode.Open,
        access: FileAccess.Read,
        share: FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite
        ), FileAccess.Read);
```

This is the error shown when Using **Cut & Paste**
[image]

This snippet demonstrates the error:

Both files exist, no other applications are using them either

```
var path = @"C:\temp\test\test.log";
var pathCopy = @"C:\temp\test.log";

var fs = new FileStream(
    File.OpenHandle(
        path,
        mode: FileMode.Open,
        access: FileAccess.Read,
        share: FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite
        ), FileAccess.Read);
    

File.Copy(pathCopy, path,true); //Works
File.Move(pathCopy, path, true); //Does NOT work -> AccessError
```

Comment: because you don't have write access?

Comment: File.Copy or move are not using the created FileStream, this is just to demonstrate that other applications are not able to use Cut & paste but can Copy & paste over the file

Comment: yeah, I get that and your should probably remove superfluous code from question. However, do you have write access to the destination, does the destination exist?

Comment: @Jodrell There is no superfluous code here, having that file handle open causes the issue in question (assuming both `path` and `pathCopy` already exist).

Comment: I have updates the code to be more clear about my issue (hopefully). Also playing around with the different flags yielded no change in behavior yet

Comment: Does `File.Delete` work? I'm not sure how much I would trust `FileShare.Delete`, I would not be completely chocked if it has some edge cases or undocumented behavior.

Comment: Why not close the handle, dispose of the filestream object?

Comment: If you are running on Windows, this is the documentation for the underlying API, that may still be used, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

Comment: File.Delete works as expected. The issue seems specific to File.Move with Overwrite = true

But my issue is that the file move in Explorer will not work - the code above is just demonstration

Comment: SafeFileHandle on its own wont work for me. https://i.imgur.com/vtHL0HZ.png